# Is it possible automatically include user to all templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

I have project in Django 1.3. In order to show username in all pages I use such tags in base.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}.  
    <a href="/proc/accounts/logout/">loggout</a></p>
{% else %}
    <a href="/proc/accounts/login/">loggin</a>
{% endif %}
```

But if I dont return `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` from view value of user in template is empty. The `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'` is included to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Is it possible automaticaly include user to all templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since django 1.3. use shortcuts.render function and dont warry about requestcontext including to your views

Answer (score 1):

You've given the answer yourself. As long as you use a RequestContext, it will be included in all templates.

If you really find that too much work, you could use the (new in 1.3) [TemplateResponse class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/template-response/#django.template.response.TemplateResponse).

Answer (score -1):

Or simply create a context processor. See
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Put this in context_processor.py

```
def root_categories(request):
    return {
        'user': request.user,
    }
```

in settings.py add the context processor.

now in your template try: {{ user }}